# My view is invalidated when I touch anywhere of screen

Tags: android

I am working on Android Tablet.

Strangely the controls in view are invalidated when I touch anywhere of my screen.

To be more precise, A textview and a progressbar are inside of LinearLayout view, and I invalidate the text of TextView with setText() function every seconds via Hanlder.
I found the text is not changed but when I touch screen the text content is changed.

I assume it is related to a focus issue.

please give me any tips. 
Thank you.

Comment: You have to explain it better

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution. 
I still don't know why the TextView is not re-drawn when I call .setText("...").
But in onCreate(), I put the below code in to get a focus (in my guess).

//getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() is a call to get top view

**getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().invalidate();**

and finally well working with invalidating.

I hope this will be useful for someone.